# LWC : How to Map Wrapper Class Values in Lightning datatable fieldname

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, wrapper-class

Is it possible to map wrapper values in lightning datatable fieldname. I'm not able to map the values in the fieldname.

Please find the code below:
Wrapper:

```
public class AccountsResponse {
    
    @AuraEnabled public List<String> accountName; 
    @AuraEnabled public List<String> accountNumber; 
    @AuraEnabled public Double quantityValue; 
    
}

Apex Method: 
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
public static AccountsResponse getWrapperResponse(String recordId){ 
        
        if(recordId == null){
            return null; 
        }
        
        //Initialize the wrapper
        AccountsResponse accResponseObj = new AccountsResponse (); 
        
        Decimal productAnnualVolume;
        Integer accountCount; 
        Double quantityValue;
        List<String> accountName = new  List<String>(); 
        List<String> accountNumber = new List<String>(); 
        
        OpportunityLineItem oppLineItemRecord = [SELECT Id, Name, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id = :recordId];
        productAnnualVolume = oppLineItemRecord.Quantity; 
        
        List<CustomObject__c> accountList = fetchAccountsFromProducts(recordId);
        
        for(CustomObject__c accObj: accountList ) {
            accountName.add(accObj.Name); 
            accountNumber.add(accObj.AccountNumber);
        }
        
        accountCount = accountList.size(); 
        
        quantityValue = productAnnualVolume/sapAccountCount; 
                
        //Assign Values into wrapper fields
        accResponseObj.accountName = accountName ; 
        accResponseObj.accountNumber = accountNumber; 
        accResponseObj.quantityValue = quantityValue; 
                            
        if(accResponseObj!=null){
            return accResponseObj; 
        }else{
            return new AccountsResponse (); 
        }
        
    }    
}

JS: 
import getWrapperResponsefrom '@salesforce/apex/AccountService.getWrapperResponse'; 

accountColumns = [
        { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: '/* Need help here - Not able to render wrapper values*/'},
        { label: 'Account Number', fieldName: '/* Need help here - Not able to render wrapper values*/'},
        { label: 'Quantity', type: 'text', fieldName: '/* Need help here - Not able to render wrapper values*/', editable: true}
    ];

    @wire(getWrapperResponse,  {recordId: '$recordId'}) 
    getWrapperResponse({error, data}) {
        if(data) {
            this.sapAccounttWrapperResponse = data;
            this.error = undefined;     
        }
        else if(error){
            this.error = error;
            this.sapAccounttWrapperResponse = undefined;
        }
    }

HTML: 
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-card title="">
          <div class="slds-p-around_xx-small">
              <lightning-datatable
                  key-field="Id"
                  data={sapAccounttWrapperResponse}
                  onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                  onsave={handleSave}
                  draft-values={saveDraftValues}
                  columns={accountColumns}>
              </lightning-datatable>
          </div>
        </lightning-card>
      </div>
  
</template>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "fieldName" it should just be the names of the variables in the wrapper?

```
{ label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'accountName'},
{ label: 'Account Number', fieldName: 'accountNumber'},
{ label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'quantityValue', editable: true}
```

If that doesn't work - try to debug by outputting the contents of the wrapper response to the console to see the structure of it...

```
...
this.sapAccounttWrapperResponse = data;    
console.log(this.sapAccounttWrapperResponse);
...
```

That said - your getWrapperResponse needs to return a List of objects...
Like this:

```
public static List<AccountsResponse> getWrapperResponse(String recordId){
```

and your wrapped object should not contain lists within it for the Datatable to work the way I think you intend it to.

```
public class AccountsResponse {
   @AuraEnabled public String accountName; 
   @AuraEnabled public String accountNumber; 
   @AuraEnabled public Double quantityValue; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I could update the accountsColumn but what should I put in fieldname. I'm stuck on the same part.

Comment: @Rose Oh, I understand what you are asking now.  I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you @Paul N for your reply. I tried with wrapper variable names but it didn't work. 
While debugging I'm getting the wrapper variables values in JS not able to map them in fieldname.

Comment: Please find the JSON 
sapAccounttWrapperResponse------>{"accountName":["Test SAP Account-1","Test SAP Account-2","Test SAP Account-3","Test SAP Account-4","Test SAP Account-5","Test SAP Account-6","Test SAP Account-8","Test SAP Account-7"],"accountNumber":["Test SAP Account Number-1","Test SAP Account Number-2","Test SAP Account Number-3","Test SAP Account Number-4","Test SAP Account Number-5","Test SAP Account Number-6","Test SAP Account Number-8","Test SAP Account Number-7"],"quantityValue":300}

Comment: @Rose I see now what the issue is.  Datatable works on a List of records.  Your wrapped object contains lists. but is not a list of records.

Comment: @Rose I added more to my answer explaining what I mean about how datatable needs a list of objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the code and wrapper as per your suggestion and it worked. Thank you for your time.